# Debugging c++ application in VSCode exits when "*" is printed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using the following application

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(char* s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    print("a"); 
    print("b");
    print("***");
    print("c");
    print("d");
}
```

When I run it with the debugger under VSCode (using "Native Debug" extension), it never pass the second print and this is my output:

```
a
b
```

It never pass `print("***)`, even if I put a breakpoint after that line it doesn't reach it.

if I comment out `print("***")`, the application finish with the correct output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

The only thing I managed to figure out is that there is and issue printing "*" character and if I replace it with any other character all works fine. Why do I see this behavior and how can I fix this without having to change the code?

Comment: Verify that you indeed have ASCII `*` characters in that string. Opening the source file in a hex editor is one way to check that. There should't be any reason why the program as posted cannot work.

Comment: The program works fine as long I don't try to debug it under VSCode. If I run it as is or  debug it using gdb, it works with no issues. In any case, I have opened it with hex editor and I see the correct ASCII value for `"***"`, 2A 2A 2A

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that you have found a bug in the VSCode debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@molbdnilo, seem to be correct. It looks like a bug in "Native Debug" extension. The problem is not reproduced when another extension is used (I tried with Microsoft's "C/C++" extension)

Comment: create an issue for this at the `Native Debug` extension